# mail header “from” domain is automatically replaced by server's domain, why?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, smtp-headers

The mail header "from" domain of any mail sent to our company's server is replaced by server's domain.

For example:

example@gmail.com send an email to our server(company.com). We see the sender of this email is example@company.com.

I do not know the reason. Please help me. Thanks!

mail system: sendmail + dovecot + saslauthd

sendmail.mc:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $Sendmail: debproto.mc,v 8.14.3 2010-08-03 06:56:05 cowboy Exp $
#
# Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
# cf/debian/sendmail.mc.  Generated from sendmail.mc.in by configure.
#
# sendmail.mc prototype config file for building Sendmail 8.14.3
#
# Note: the .in file supports 8.7.6 - 9.0.0, but the generated
#   file is customized to the version noted above.
#
# This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
# If you modify this file, you will have to regenerate /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# by running this file through the m4 preprocessor via one of the following:
#   * make   (or make -C /etc/mail)
#   * sendmailconfig 
#   * m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# The first two options are preferred as they will also update other files
# that depend upon the contents of this file.
#
# The best documentation for this .mc file is:
# /usr/share/doc/sendmail-doc/cf.README.gz
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
divert(0)dnl
#
#   Copyright (c) 1998-2005 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
#  This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
include(`/etc/mail/sasl/sasl.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`$Id: sendmail.mc, v 8.14.3-9.2ubuntu1 2010-08-03 06:56:05 cowboy Exp $')
OSTYPE(`debian')dnl
DOMAIN(`debian-mta')dnl
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
undefine(`confHOST_STATUS_DIRECTORY')dnl        #DAEMON_HOSTSTATS=

dnl #
dnl # General defines
dnl #
dnl # SAFE_FILE_ENV: [undefined] If set, sendmail will do a chroot()
dnl #   into this directory before writing files.
dnl #   If *all* your user accounts are under /home then use that
dnl #   instead - it will prevent any writes outside of /home !
dnl #   define(`confSAFE_FILE_ENV',             `')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Daemon options - restrict to servicing LOCALHOST ONLY !!!
dnl # Remove `, Addr=' clauses to receive from any interface
dnl # If you want to support IPv6, switch the commented/uncommentd lines
dnl #
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl

TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A') dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=0.0.0.0')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea Addr=0.0.0.0')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP, Port=25 M=Ea')dnl

define(`confDEF_USER_ID',``mail:mail'')dnl
undefine(`UUCP_RELAY')dnl
undefine(`BITNET_RELAY')dnl
define(`confRUN_AS_USER',`root:smmsp')dnl
define(`confTRUSTED_USER', `smmsp')dnl
define(`confTRUSTED_USER', `smmta')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST',true)dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',true)dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH',`/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/etc/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `5000000')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
dnl #define(QUEUE_DIR,`/var/spool/mqueue/q*')dnl
define(`confMAX_MESSAGE_SIZE',`40000000')dnl
dnl # added for dns problem defer
define(`confBIND_OPTS', `WorkAroundBrokenAAAA')dnl


dnl #
dnl # Be somewhat anal in what we allow
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',dnl
`needmailhelo,needexpnhelo,needvrfyhelo,restrictqrun,restrictexpand,nobodyreturn,authwarnings')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Define connection throttling and window length
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `15')dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`10m')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Features
dnl #
dnl # use /etc/mail/local-host-names
FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl
dnl FEATURE(`use_ct_file')dnl

dnl # Delay_checks allows sender<->recipient checking
FEATURE(local_procmail,`',`procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl

dnl #
dnl # The access db is the basis for most of sendmail's checking
FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl

FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
dnl # blacklist to stop spams
dnl #FEATURE(`dnsbl', `cblless.anti-spam.org.cn')dnl
dnl #FEATURE(`enhdnsbl', `cblplus.anti-spam.org.cn', `"Server address listed at cblplus.anti-spam.org.cn"', `t')dnl
FEATURE(`enhdnsbl', `zen.spamhaus.org', `"Spam blocked see: http://www.abuse.net/sbl.phtml?IP="$&{client_addr}', `t')dnl
dnl #FEATURE(`access_db',`hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl


dnl #
dnl # The greet_pause feature stops some automail bots - but check the
dnl # provided access db for details on excluding localhosts...
FEATURE(`greet_pause', `1000')dnl 1 seconds
dnl #
dnl # Delay_checks allows sender<->recipient checking
FEATURE(`delay_checks', `friend', `n')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If we get too many bad recipients, slow things down...
define(`confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE',`3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Stop connections that overflow our concurrent and time connection rates
FEATURE(`conncontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
FEATURE(`ratecontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If you're on a dialup link, you should enable this - so sendmail
dnl # will not bring up the link (it will queue mail for later)
dnl define(`confCON_EXPENSIVE',`True')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Dialup/LAN connection overrides
dnl #
include(`/etc/mail/m4/dialup.m4')dnl
include(`/etc/mail/m4/provider.m4')dnl

FEATURE(`smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable',`hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
dnl # add 2013-11-8
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(hotmail.com)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/masquerade-domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(xxx.xxx.edu.cn)dnl

dnl #
dnl # 
dnl # Also accept email sent to "localhost.localdomain" as local email.
dnl # 
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`xxx.xxx.edu.cn')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`xxx.xxx.cn')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`xxx.cs.xxx.edu.cn')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`xxx.cs.xxx.cn')dnl

dnl # Default Mailer setup
dnl #MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
MAILER(`procmail')dnl
MAILER(`local')dnl
```

Two examples:

163:

```
From example@company.com  Wed Dec 21 21:47:26 2016 
Return-Path: <example@company.com> 
Received: from m13-141.163.com (m13-141.163.com [220.181.13.141]) 
    by company.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id uBLDlPiQ013409 
    for <xxx@company.com>; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 21:47:26 +0800 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=163.com; 
    s=s110527; h=Date:From:Subject:MIME-Version:Message-ID; bh=hpaD0 
    qA4I59smafOVhBxwFe3a15FCNfA2uxigC6sgOY=; b=JdNTQe6QHM1TCcgvPCHtw 
    0Lkr1iMuJpydrsSpywGH8QnwV0hMucgh0IO+jg4THKW+2hr/IaVbQJoJabx2W/Mr 
    nQ2YWwc7ECDVaFqU9HJJygtqcrP3d2cp3qBbGlq/YVUUkXidTeX52kQStnULVBzk 
    FEJFuAYeRA/4XZyeo5LxNM= 
Received: from example$163.com ( [192.198.95.71, 54.215.2.217, 10.144.1.72] ) 
by ajax-webmail-wmsvr141 (Coremail) ; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 21:46:07 +0800 (CST) 
X-Originating-IP: [192.198.95.71, 54.215.2.217, 10.144.1.72] 
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 21:46:07 +0800 (CST) 
From: "example" <example@company.com> 
To: "xxx@company.com" <xxx@company.com> 
Subject: aaaaa 
X-Priority: 3 
X-Mailer: Coremail Webmail Server Version SP_ntes V3.5 build 
20160729(86883.8884) Copyright (c) 2002-2016 www.mailtech.cn 163com 
X-CM-CTRLDATA: RB7qyGZvb3Rlcl9odG09MjcyNTo1Ng== 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_12111914_355555859.1482327967157" 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Message-ID: <7e744d1.2de269.15921a1c5b6.Coremail.xysmlx@163.com> 
X-Coremail-Locale: zh_CN 
X-CM-TRANSID:jcGowACXpqKfh1pYSOaiAA--.29831W 
X-CM-SenderInfo: p01vzzr06rljoofrz/1tbiNQ1HvlSIRLiDogABsB 
X-Coremail-Antispam: 1U5529EdanIXcx71UUUUU7vcSsGvfC2KfnxnUU== 
Status: RO 
X-UID: 336                                                   
Content-Length: 4432
```

gmail:

```
From example@company.com  Wed Dec 21 22:52:39 2016 
Return-Path: <example@company.com> 
Received: from mail-ua0-f178.google.com (mail-ua0-f178.google.com [209.85.217.178]) 
    by company.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id uBLEqbPm019461 
    for <xxx@company.com>; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 22:52:38 +0800 
Received: by mail-ua0-f178.google.com with SMTP id 2so79983525uax.2 
       for <xxx@company.com>; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 06:52:00 -0800 (PST) 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
       d=gmail.com; s=20161025; 
       h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; 
       bh=+fBXgxbVSyjlxMpSNMOsZLbhE2bqAQI97mJviWO7ebE=; 
       b=l1SM9poejQhkOB7y725tK1K8oCsbxSENpl+po0nU+AHzyNE0BguFHgLLrFMj7vnuPG 
        ARR0mhWhVow3Pikzeq+IrymrsbnEqyOwgehR/ztTYDY8TPfpghK3O7eRPr9XVhC8oFs+ 
        Il9rCu324IljhOstd/5cWhGkwhA/m2F1bLUoxYw0O18GLVE85uQnH7PZe04W21vPLDVq 
        fuJlrbNFSo4Fxbe626IaS/1CVIUrs5Wkz1YExfa7pADbiqc3RNrEErBrk4FfWRPdHN/y 
        7z7PxqpHvBs+SG2IMx5eCRA5zdsczQvNXHIy3yIHvwkeydYi77PPzR8qUZ2pSfomzmKu 
        LKCg== 
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
       d=1e100.net; s=20161025; 
       h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; 
       bh=+fBXgxbVSyjlxMpSNMOsZLbhE2bqAQI97mJviWO7ebE=; 
       b=CzacaxE4CvL4uxlG4qUkbEm+vAiix3+UR+I7D0xechpMyOGoGrjE/rVfOXl/Zk+8Rr 
        +F4xjJ+kTd7jv1C5d1NGk7CtjMl8mZpUk2bE7WesYV8PryUbY7b6mHpB7XjL3J3AD90o 
        UVPpyX9vjeVJ89E03a1rg05yILGEHWh/E3+bByw68HPxdyCss2I0Tri98030QBWRHasj 
        7BX6qswHzpo2+87yvRpcsBqoSoKgz4L7ydPMt+zXCmxN2VCqw5MX6vLyzuaOIyWR6RFd 
        Uda7z9lqKw8bOo1ntxaMSTwiHmRWZyWtarvB/1MxPRySsJDIc+4tw1YLbfBNNYiWf3C8 
        /SMQ== 
X-Gm-Message-State: AIkVDXKc6Fge9ySWKwRQDYsVUzsuNqgZ9VBci7aM/TEGB915XFQonbYpgBCqBzht712z1QTbDXlrek9X6dKWfA== 
X-Received: by 10.176.85.139 with SMTP id v11mr632414uaa.7.1482331912496; Wed, 
21 Dec 2016 06:51:52 -0800 (PST) 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Received: by 10.176.16.145 with HTTP; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 06:51:12 -0800 (PST) 
From: example <example@company.com> 
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 22:51:12 +0800 
Message-ID: <CAO+bwXcoowGtdtZBsQB44K27gUtCJEbpuRKpPj=w66YDQE828g@mail.gmail.com> 
Subject: fdasfdasfdasdasffdas 
To: xxx@company.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=f403045e286e156bca05442c4b0d 
X-UID: 340                                                   
Status: RO 
Content-Length: 2500
```

Comment: Add the configuration of your MTA to the question.

Comment: I have added the sendmail.mc file to the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off the [masquerading options](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading.html):

> You can have your host masquerade as another using

```
  MASQUERADE_AS(`host.domain')
```

> This causes mail being sent to be labeled as coming from the indicated host.domain, rather than $j.